# zooming different image in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, zooming

I try to create a zoom function using a button to activate the binding for my mouse, in my project but it only zooms the canvas and the images that I put on my canvas do not zoom in and out. This is my code for my zooming and panning.

```
def zoom():
    canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", zoom1)
    canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda event: canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y))
    canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1))
def zoom1(event):
    factor = 1.001 ** event.delta
    canvas.scale(ALL, event.x, event.y, factor, factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the documented behavior. If you want the image to resize, you must directly resize the image either using the features provided by the `PhotoImage` class, or through a library such as Pillow.

From the official tk documentation:

> Rescale the coordinates of all of the items given by tagOrId in canvas coordinate space. ... Note that some items have only a single pair of coordinates (e.g., text, images and windows) and so scaling of them by this command can only move them around.